# WHY can't we use conservation of energy to find speed of the earth around the sun?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

I was trying to calculate the velocity of the earth around the suns orbit using the conservation of mechanical energy hence:

$$\frac{GMm}{R} = \frac{mv^2}{2}$$
$$\sqrt{\frac{2GM}{R}} = v$$

why is the last equation wrong?

and what would be the correct way to find it?

update already find the correct way but I still dont understand why the first one is not true:

$$a = \frac{v^2}{R} = \frac{GMm}{R^2m}$$
$$v^2 = \frac{GM}{R}$$
$$v = \sqrt{\frac{GM}{R}}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conservation of energy is useful when different forms of energy are converted into one another. The Earth's orbit around the sun is very nearly circular and at constant speed. This means the gravitational potential and kinetic energy are each constant - they are not being converted into one another.

However, if you instead had a planet in a highly elliptical orbit, the gravitational potential and kinetic energy are converted into one another over the course of the orbit. You could then use conservation of energy to find the relationship between the speed and radius of the orbit at different times. Say for points 1 and 2 in the orbit with radius and velocity $r_{1,2}$ and $v_{1,2}$ respectively

$$E_1 = \frac{-GMm}{r_1}+\frac{1}{2}mv_1^2 = \frac{-GMm}{r_2} + \frac{1}{2}mv_2^2=E_2$$

For the Earth $r_1 \approx r_2$ and $v_1 \approx v_2$ for any two points in the orbit, so conservation of energy doesn't really tell us anything new.

Comment: why is that when I relate the centripetal aceleration with the force of gravity I get the correct answer?

Comment: @PulsarPlasma The Earth has a circular orbit, so the net force (gravity) must equal the centripetal force.

Answer (score 14):

It is correct that
$$
-\frac{GmM}{R}+ \frac 12 mv^2= constant,
$$
but  you assumed that the constant is zero. It is not necessarily so.

Comment: why  is that constant 1/2?

Comment: it depends on the initial conditions.

Comment: why is that when I relate the centripetal aceleration with the force of gravity I get the correct answer?

Comment: You seem to be puzzled by the fact that you get the right answer from a correct equation while you get the  wrong answer from a wrong equation.  Can you explain the logic of this?

Comment: The constant is half because of Virial theorem

Answer (score 7):

> ... using the conservation of mechanical energy hence:
> $$\frac{GMm}{R} = \frac{mv^2}{2}$$

This is not correct, and it is not the conservation of energy.
Instead, the conservation of energy is:
$$\underbrace{\frac{mv^2}{2}}_{E_\text{kin}}
\ \underbrace{- \frac{GMm}{R}}_{E_\text{pot}} = E = \text{const}$$
On the left side, the first part is the [kinetic energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_energy#Newtonian_kinetic_energy) of the earth.
And the second part is the [gravitational potential energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_energy) between earth and sun.

In this equation you don't know the value of the total energy $E$
(especially it is not zero).
You only know that it stays constant over time (even if velocity $v$
and radius $R$ both change over time during the elliptical movement of the earth).
Hence, this equation doesn't enable you to calculate the velocity $v$.

---

The calculation via the forces is based
on the approximation that the earth moves
nearly in a circular orbit.
The [centripetal force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_force) in a circular orbit is
$$F_\text{centripetal}=\frac{mv^2}{R}$$
and the [gravitational force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_universal_gravitation) is
$$F_\text{grav}=\frac{GMm}{R^2}$$
Both forces are the same, because otherwise it would not result in a  circular orbit.

Comment: why is that when I relate the centripetal aceleration with the force of gravity I get the correct answer?

Comment: @PulsarPlasma see the added second part of the answer

Answer (score 4):

A gravitationally bound system (like a planet in a circular orbit) has less energy than the same masses widely separated but with no kinetic energy.

If you assembled a planet and a star by pushing them together, you would have to remove energy to get them in a circular orbit.  That energy was removed during the formation of the system through collisions and interactions with other bodies.

The formation of the planetary system is not energy-conserving, so you cannot use a conservation of energy argument to reach a valid conclusion here.

Comment: why is that when I relate the centripetal aceleration with the force of gravity I get the correct answer?

Comment: Because the force of gravity is what holds the planet in orbit.  There are no other forces.